# Wireless to Ethernet via WDS function

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wds

I have a TP-Link TL-WR740N router, and a (older) Dynalink RTA1025W router. Both advertise support for WDS, or Wireless Distribution System.

So I set up the TP-Link with the internet, security, etc.

Now what I want is for the devices connected via Ethernet to the Dynalink to be on the network.

So basically what I've done is set the Wireless Repeater function on the Dynalink's setup to the TP-Link's SSID. I need to know more about WDS etc but haven't found anything helpful.

Here's a diagram:

```
                |||||||||||||
  Internet ---- |  TP-Link  |
                |||||||||||||
                |
             (( + ))


   (( ^ ))             (( ^ ))
      |                   |
----------------          |||||||||||||
| wifi clients |          | Dynalink  |>> ---- (ethernet clients in other room)
----------------          |||||||||||||
```

EDIT: no responses so thought I'd give some additional info that may help - the Dynalink's setup screen for the repeater function offers "Repeater Only" or "Repeater and Access point mode", and lets you tick a box for the wifi signal to repeat. The TP-Link's setup screen offers "WDS Bridging" and let's you choose an AP to bridge, and *asks you to type the password* (something the Dyanlink one never does). Hopefully somebody can help. I did have this working with the TP-Link bridging the Dynalink, but that's not the way round I want it. Also that connection was erratic when it worked.

Edit 3 wks later to bump - still after a way

Comment: are you looking to create a wireless bridge with the Dynalink?

Comment: Yes. I've sort of given up now - this question was asked a year ago :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure WDS is really what you need? Based on your diagram, it looks like the Dynalink should act as a client bridge, not a WDS bridge.  You may have better success with this method.  The stock firmware on the Dynalink may not support client bridge mode, so consider a third-party firmware like DD-WRT or OpenWRT.

Answer (score 1):

As Dagelf mentions, WDS between different vendors is usually broken.

What might work for you is flashing openWRT to your tp-link router and using the dynalink on your lan border (i.e. where you currently have the tp-link):
http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/tl-wr740n

And use the tp-link as your wireless bridge using pseudobridge with relayd (google it, I don't have enough reputation for another link)

Although I found a simple routed client easier to setup and more stable, YMMV:
http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/recipes/routedclient

On the downside, it's less transparent and breaks any lan service that depends on broadcast.

Basically what you do is create a separate subnetwork for your bridged hosts. The tp-link connects via wireless to the dynalink, and acts as gateway for the ethernet clients. You can either do masquerading or not for this subnetwork.

If you don't masquerade, you have to make sure that the dynalink has a route back to the new subnetwork and that it does nat for it as well. Not all home routers support this.

I have the exact same setup I described and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is looking for an answer, I believe the solution was posted at another forum [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1939095&p=11788469). Make sure you read post [#5](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1939095&p=11788469#post11788469) and [#6](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1939095&p=11791209#post11791209).

Answer (score -1):

There are several flavours of WDS. At its most basic you need to:

- set both routers to the same 802.11 mode (ie. b/g or both - **No 802.11-n Mode!**)
- the same channel
- the same SSID
- the same security which should be either no security, or WEP (**no WPA!**)

WDS mode is usually a checkbox setting at the bottom of the wireless settings when you're in pure AP (Access Point) mode.

"Repeater mode" is likely not WDS, but some other form of wireless client mode.

### Some background:

Quite often WDS implementations between different vendors are broken - or even between different models of the same vendor (as is the case with TP-Link). I have no experience with Dynalink - it's quite likely that what their menu item calls WDS is in fact not WDS and rather some esoteric bridge mode.

There are several different ways to implement the functionality required in the firmware, each with it's own cocktail of peculiarities; the standards on these things aren't very clearly written and usually up to the whims of the firmware engineers at the vendor.